# What version of VB to use as a beginner?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have *never* programmed VB, but a university course forcibly requires me to use it. Now, I've done VC++/Win32 programming before, but not the CLR(.NET). There's this free IDE from Microsoft, Visual Basic.NET express, that I plan to learn on. Is that okay? I mean I'm not learning .NET stuff, it'll be plain old Win32 with VB. Is that possible on that IDE? Will it require(read: force) me to use the .NET libraries instead? If yes, is there a free copy of VB 6 (or anything NOT NET) IDE still available? Excuse me if this sound noobish, but I really haven't *ever* touched on VB or .nET development.

Comment: No, with Express you need to use .NET.

... a *university* course that *requires* you to use *VB6*???

Comment: Please tell us which University requires you to use obsolete software that is no longer supported by the vendor. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708/

Comment: what's the last version that was NOT NET?

Comment: Does VB.NET Express not support P/Invoke?

Comment: Sorry, VB6 is dead, and it was the last non-.NET version. Why do you want to avoid .NET ?

Comment: VB6 was the last such version, and it's not supported. It's a matter of cruelty, if not stupidity, to teach a beginner VB6. It's anti-education.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Sure it does, but you can't develop things that don't require .NET libraries...

Comment: @minitech: they might require .NET libraries to be _present_, yet do all the Win32 stuff through P/Invoke.

Comment: @JohnSaunders They call it "Visual programming" - I've seen people hate that language with passion - that is a big turn-off, plus the constant down of writing old crap when you know there's something *lot* better available!

Comment: If the course is on "Visual Programming", they should use VB.NET Express. All they're teaching with VB6 is how stupid they are. The VB6 IDE and compiler haven't been supported since 2008.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have no issues having the .NET runtime installed - please let me know if I can still do Win32 on express. btw what is P/Invoke?

Comment: P/Invoke (Platform Invoke) is a method of calling code like Win32 code from a .NET program. I find it hard to believe this course, to be honest. Are you sure you haven't misinterpreted it? Many course descriptions might say "Visual Basic" assuming it means "VB.NET".

Comment: @JohnSaunders just had a look at the syllabus now - they don't mention the version - the description is more like knowing the *language* than the platform - But I had seen the dreaded 6 IDE on one of the lab comps. - has the core language changed significantly since then?

Comment: yatisagade: Yes, significantly. @JohnSaunders: What's the point of doing that? May as well use C/C++.

Comment: @minitech: the point would depend on what the course is about. If it's about a stupid university that has its head in ... the sand ... then they'll require the students to use obsolete and unsupported software that will be of little or no use to them.

Comment: @yatisagade: perhaps you can get the instructor or someone else from the University to see this discussion and to answer why they think there is value in learning obsolete unsupported software. Seriously, it hasn't been supported since 2008.

Comment: @JohnSaunders right! I'll go for .NET! - VB AND C# at the same time. To hell with the university course - I'll pass it somehow! thanks ;-)

Comment: @yatisagade: I didn't say to dump the course. I'm just telling you it will teach you more about the instructors than about modern software development. Perhaps you can take the course but, on your own, do the exercises with VB.NET in addition to VB6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have never learned old Win32 with VB aka VB6, I would advise you to skip it altogether and learn VB.net unless your end goal is to maintain legacy applications.

The concepts and libraries that you learn as part of VB.net will be transferable to C# which seems to be the most popular .NET language at the moment

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET and "regular" VB are vastly different. VB6 was the last release of VB6 that is not managed. I question the value of learning this though. VB6 is unsupported, products for it are unsupported, and there isn't much you can gain by learning it instead of learning something else like VB.NET. If you really are stuck learning plain VB (which hasn't had an update since 1998), then you'll have a hard time finding resources.

VB.NET really means "A VB-like syntax language for .NET". Since the Express edition is for VB.NET, you cannot use it for VB development.

Your best bet is to find a copy of Visual Studio 6 or Visual Basic 6 Professional. You can still purchase them from places like [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002S7HR).

MSDN Downloads has VB6 as well. You should contact your school to see if they can provide any additional resources. Perhaps your school can get you an Academic MSDN license (though I am not sure if that would include VB6).

You can forget about running those IDEs on Windows Vista or Windows 7. You'll need a copy of XP / 2000 as well.

Comment: VB6 and the Visual Studio 6 IDE is still functional on Windows 7 32bit. I, sadly, know this for a fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the free Visual Basic 2008/2010 Express edition.